# Python Ros - Alternative way to map a sine wave to motor

Tags: python, ros, trigonometry

Currently I have a motor running in ROS that correctly maps a sine wave which i can see via the "rqt_plot" function in the terminal. The code is like so to get the desired effect:

```
    pub = rospy.Publisher("/tilt_controller/command", Float64, latch=True)

global cmd
cmd = 5.0
global count 
count = 0
global count2
count2=0
def state_callback(msg):
    #rospy.loginfo(msg)
    #print msg.current_pos
    global cmd
    global count
    global count2
    period = 50
    M = 2
    count = count +1
    if count==10:
        count = 0
        count2 = count2+1
        if count2 == period:
            count2 =0
        cmd = M*math.sin(((2*math.pi)/period)*count2)
        #cmd = cmd*(-1)
        pub.publish(cmd)

    #rospy.sleep(2.0)



def led_control_demo():

    rospy.init_node('led_control_demo')

    #rospy.Subscriber("/motor_states/pan_tilt_port", MotorStateList, motor_callback)

    rospy.Subscriber("/tilt_controller/state", JointState, state_callback)

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     #rospy.init.node("led_control_demo")
     led_control_demo()
```

Although the code maps the sine wave fairly accurately I am looking at alternative ways to possibly improve its accuracy but have hit a wall. Can anyone suggest or think of an alternative method to more accurately map my dynamixel motor to the sine wave. Hope this was clear enough and thank you.

Comment: Your quesition seems to be better off at the [codereview section](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: CodeReview is good if you want feedback on code style and general Python issues; it is not good if you need help with specialized module like `rospy`.  There are more specialists on SO.